# Ways to create a Minesweeper table in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a Minesweeper game in Java but there is a question: Why is the first attempt not working (lines 3-7)? I mean, supposed to add the buttons on the screen but it doesn't appear.

Probably the problem is in the `GameButton` constructor but IDK.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    for(int k=0; k<size; k++) {
        /* this one don't work
        butt[i][k] = new GameButton(i,k);
        contentPane1.add(butt[i][k]);
        */

        // this one works well
        Button button_1 = new Button("?");
        contentPane1.add(button_1);
    }   
}


class GameButton extends JButton {
    int row, col;
    public GameButton(int row, int col){
        this.row = row;
        this.row = col;
    }
}
```

### Full code

```
package gui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
//import mapa.*;
//import jogo.*;

public class Gameplay extends JFrame {

    GameButton[][] butt;
    private int size;
    private JPanel contentPane1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Gameplay frame2 = new Gameplay("MEDIO");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Gameplay(String dificuldade) {
        this.setTitle("Minesweeper");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane1 = new JPanel();
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane1);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        if (dificuldade.contentEquals("MEDIO")) {
            size = 16;
        }

        contentPane1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(size, size));

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                /* this one don't work
                 butt[i][k] = new GameButton(i,k);
                 contentPane1.add(butt[i][k]);
                 */

                // this one works well
                Button button_1 = new Button("?");
                contentPane1.add(button_1);

            }
        }
    }

    class GameButton extends JButton {

        int row, col;

        public GameButton(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.row = col;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have referred to it 'not working in line 49' but no-one knows what your error is, or which line is line 49...

Comment: @DavidBuck sorry, fixed it!

Comment: I can't help but notice that `GameButton` extends [`JButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JButton.html) (a Swing class), but the version that works uses [`Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Button.html) (a base AWT class), not `JButton`. So...are you using Swing, or not?

Comment: You still haven't said what "don't work" means. Also, your `GameButton` code never sets any label or icon on the button.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm trying, but isn't working :c

Comment: I think I see what the problem is from the linked code. On StackOverflow you want to cut it down to a minimal complete example of the code. So do that first - if you do that you'll probably find your problem on your own.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW `import jogo.*;` What's Jogo? Try to reproduce the problem using only core Java classes.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline See edit. (The code at the pastebin included what was essentially an MRE / SSCCE, barring two unnecessary imports. So I commented them out, reformatted it & edited into the question.)

Comment: @DavidBuck See edit. (& comment above to Tom. Note the line numbers might not be exactly the same due to formatting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `GameButton` array is null. It is necessary to initialize it before use.

So this:

```
GameButton[][] butt;
```

Should be more like this:

```
GameButton[][] butt = new GameButton[1][1];
```

(But change the number from '1')

---

### Edit

I realized the situation was a little more complex than in the first part of the answer. The grid of places in the minefield is set by the `size`. But the `size` is not set until the constructor is invoked.

So the approach then would be to initialize the `GameButton` array *after* the `size` has been determined.

Like this. Also look carefully at the code comments.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Gameplay extends JFrame {

    private int size;
    GameButton[][] butt;
    private JPanel contentPane1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Gameplay frame2 = new Gameplay("MEDIO");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Gameplay(String dificuldade) {
        this.setTitle("Minesweeper");
        // instead of doing this, which is no more than a guess, 
        // add the components then pack() the frame.
        //setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane1 = new JPanel();
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane1);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        if (dificuldade.contentEquals("MEDIO")) {
            size = 16;
        }
        butt = new GameButton[size][size];

        contentPane1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(size, size));

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                butt[i][k] = new GameButton(i, k);
                contentPane1.add(butt[i][k]);
            }
        }
        this.pack();
    }

    class GameButton extends JButton {

        int row, col;

        public GameButton(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.row = col;
        }
    }
}
```